# Showing Initial Column Sort Header in NSTableView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit

Working in Swift and AppKit on macOS: I have an `NSTableView` which is all working as expected - except the table does not show any column header sort indicator when it initially loads.

My table content is sorting as expected on the initial load, and clicking on column headers to sort works as expected (including showing the column header sort indicator) - it's just the indicator on the *initial* load isn't working.

Based on [NSTableView and displaying sort image in column header question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038554/nstableview-and-displaying-sort-image-in-column-header-question) I've tried adding the following to my `viewDidLoad` - but it seems to make no difference whatsoever:

```
let timeStampColumn = backupsTable.tableColumn(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "Timestamp"))

backupsTable.setIndicatorImage(NSImage(named: "NSDescendingSortIndicator"), in: timeStampColumn!)
```

What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `backupsTable.sortDescriptors` to the initial sort descriptors.

Comment: Thankyou thank you @Willeke!  I had seen that .setSortDescriptors was available in Obj-C, but not in Swift - my bad for not seeing that .sortDescriptors was a {set} property too.